# Handling custom selection style in view based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface, nstableview

How do I go about drawing my own custom selection style for a view based `NSTableView`? I tried putting a `BOOL` var in my `NSTableCellView` subclass and set that to `YES` if it is clicked and then I can successfully draw my custom selection. But how do I change that `BOOL` var to `NO` when another view is clicked? Thanks for any help.

EDIT: After reading through the NSTableView docs, it looks like I need to subclass NSTableRowView to override the selection drawing, but what do I do with my NSTableRowView subclass? How do I get the table to use it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. You just have to subclass `NSTableRowView`. It has methods for drawing the background for selected and deselected rows. To get the table view to use your subclass just implement the table view delegate method `tableView:rowViewForRow:` and return an instance of your subclass.

Comment: How can I change the label color and the icon in the cell view?

Answer (score 1):

To make things clear, I think we should give the code of the delegate method :

```
- (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row
{
   MyNSTableRowView *rowView = [[MyNSTableRowView alloc]init];
   return rowView;
}
```